# Python curve_fit with measured data points

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-analysis, measurement

I have measured data points, I want to fit against a formula to determine two entities. However I get the error :

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

produced by the following python code (I use version 3):

```
 import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(T, fun, Tc):
    return fun*np.sqrt(np.cos(np.pi/2*(T/Tc)^2))

xdata=(4.61, 4.89, 4.92, 4.95, 5.06, 5.10, 5.21, 5.38, 5.41, 5.57, 5.80, 6.14, 6.61, 7.27, 7.66, 7.90, 8.91, 8.29, 8.23, 7.30, 7.86,
       8.30, 8.89, 8.99, 9.24, 9.35, 9.50, 8.77, 8.27, 8.37, 7.72, 7.57, 7.99, 8.13) # these are temperature values <-> T

ydata=(2.85, 2.84, 2.83, 2.825, 2.82, 2.81, 2.80, 2.765, 2.76, 2.74, 2.695, 2.62, 2.50, 2.265, 2.105, 1.975, 1.23, 1.75, 1.81, 2.26,
       2.005, 1.75, 1.31, 1.14, 1.015, 1.045, 1.06, 1.40, 1.75, 1.69, 2.075, 2.15, 1.93, 1.855) # these are energy values <-> func

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
popt #display these optimized values
```

Here comes the above error!!!

I saw a way to do it if you have a fixed formula and add some noise, but I have measured data points (they must be discrete).

Thank you!
     Carsten

Comment: The power operator is `**` not `^`...  `^` means "Bitwise Exclusive Or"

Comment: @DavidG that is a nice catch, well done.

Comment: When I use **, I get a different error after popt:

C:\Users\B\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app 


And later after the same cell:


RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 600.

Comment: That is a different problem. You need to ask another question (the answer to which is you probably need to provide an initial guess to the `curve_fit` using the argument `p0=`)

Comment: So I shouldn't edit the question, but let it stay and ask a new question? (I'm new to stackoverflow)

Comment: And you think that it takes too long for the kernel to calculate that fit so that he stops after 600 tries, therefore I have to give python some initial round about correct values that it can optimize?

Comment: Please try these starting parameters of Tc =  9.7 and fun =  2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a big part of the error you are seeing is that you have not supplied initial values for the fitting variables `fun` and `Tc`.  Unfortunately scipy's `curve_fit()` allows this and silently assigns the values to be 1.0, which is encourages bad practice and is a very bad "feature".  Don't use it.

Allow me to recommend lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py) which provides a higher level interface to curve fitting that is easier to use, better at avoiding bad behavior, and has lots of useful features unavailable with `curve_fit()`.

With lmfit, your fit problem would look like (I changed a few variable names for clarity):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def func(t, scale, tc):
    return scale*np.sqrt(np.cos(np.pi/2*(t/tc)**2))

tdata = np.array([4.61, 4.89, 4.92, 4.95, 5.06, 5.10, 5.21, 5.38, 5.41, 5.57, 5.80, 6.14, 6.61, 7.27, 7.66, 7.90, 8.91, 8.29, 8.23, 7.30, 7.86,
                  8.30, 8.89, 8.99, 9.24, 9.35, 9.50, 8.77, 8.27, 8.37, 7.72, 7.57, 7.99, 8.13]) # these are temperature values <-> T

energy = np.array([2.85, 2.84, 2.83, 2.825, 2.82, 2.81, 2.80, 2.765, 2.76, 2.74, 2.695, 2.62, 2.50, 2.265, 2.105, 1.975, 1.23, 1.75, 1.81, 2.26,
                   2.005, 1.75, 1.31, 1.14, 1.015, 1.045, 1.06, 1.40, 1.75, 1.69, 2.075, 2.15, 1.93, 1.855]) # these are energy values <-> func

fmodel = Model(func)

params = fmodel.make_params(scale=5, tc=10)

result = fmodel.fit(energy, params, t=tdata)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(tdata, energy, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(tdata, result.best_fit, '+', label='fit')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which will print out a report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(func)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 24
    # data points      = 34
    # variables        = 2
    chi-square         = 0.34988407
    reduced chi-square = 0.01093388
    Akaike info crit   = -151.601474
    Bayesian info crit = -148.548753
[[Variables]]
    scale:  2.87776739 +/- 0.02737439 (0.95%) (init = 5)
    tc:     9.68051725 +/- 0.03597889 (0.37%) (init = 10)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(scale, tc) = -0.506
```

and produce a graph like

[image]

Comment: How did you get to scale = 5 (band gap of the superconductor at T=0K) and tc=10 (critical temperature of the superconductor - Niobium)?
You did just try some values and tested what gave a result? (In reality these values come from a physical estimate?)

Comment: The physical values are correct by comparison with the literature (approx) and I could reproduce it after installing 'lmfit'. I don't know how this is usually seen in the python community, but installing new packages has always the risk that there is a mistake somewhere in there isn't it? - So I'll mark as correct. Still an answer without new package (or different ones for those who prefer others) is still very welcome - ty very much Mister Newvielle for your help.

Comment: To guess initial values, I plotted the data and saw: a) max  energy (y) value ~ 2.5, and b) max t (x) value ~ 10.   Those would have been better guesses(!) but I used those to guess that `scale` was probably between 1 and 10 (so 5) and `tc` was probably between 1 and 100 (so 10).  Visualizing data can be remarkably useful!   With the right starting values, you should get identical results with `curve_fit` or `leastsq`. lmfit uses `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` by default.  All software has the risk of mistakes.  In this case, curve_fit was demonstrated to be worse than lmfit ;).